# Cannot upgrade TYPO3 from 4.5 to 6.2

Tags: php, typo3

A TYPO3 4.4.15 site has been disabled by the remote host's upgrade of PHP to version 5.6.23.  Reading the TYPO3 [upgrade docs](https://wiki.typo3.org/Upgrade#Upgrading_to_6.1) suggests the upgrade path of the TYPO3 installation to something compatible with 5.6 is:
`4.4.15 -> 4.6.n -> 4.7.n -> 6.0.n -> 6.1.n -> 6.2.n -> 7 LTS`

This is likely the safest path. Is there an equally safe but shorter path? [All work will be done in a VM sandbox.]

#### Edit 1

Made it through 4.5.40.  All update steps pass, all database mods accomplished. Tarball of 4.5 created, mysqldump created.  Both copied to VM with PHP 5.6. Tarball extracted, database recreated with dump. Launching site with `typo3_src -> ../typo3_src-6.2.30`, database mod fails with:

```
Database update failed
Error: Data truncated for column 'adminusers' at row 1
```

#### Edit #2

Changed title from `Shortest safe path from TYPO3 4.4.15 to 7 LTS` to `Cannot upgrade TYPO3 from 4.5 to 6.2`.

Above occurs even after adding `smooth_migration`. Hate to see what a bumpy migration is!

#### Edit #3:

Got past the `adminusers` error by truncating `sys_workspace`. Upgrades performed through the install tool.  Now chasing bugs with a supposedly upgraded site.  It's astounding how stuff noted years ago persists.

#### Edit #4:

Errors received after upgrade all see to relate to references to requiring `PATH_t3lib...` items.  Each error that appeared in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` was addressed as front & back end screens were refreshed until no further errors occurred.

### Edit #5:

Once error-free, the site is missing both left & right columns of a three column setup. I do not know how to recreate them and am largely disinclined to go back to figure out how and where the got lost. But I'm open to hints on finding them, not recreating them. I'll upvote the answer below but not accept because I don't think I've fully upgraded the site.

#### Edit #6:

In going back over the process I learned that elements had actually disappeared on the conversion from 4.4 to 4.5.  What's curious, but beyond my concern for now at least, is that the "missing" elements appear in the backend.  They just are not displayed on the page where they appeared in 4.4.

Answer (score 3):

4.4 -> 4.5 (LTS) -> 6.2 (LTS) -> 7.6 (LTS) -> 8.7 (LTS)

LTS to LTS is a safe way.

6.2 is already compatible with PHP 5.6.

Comment: Backup before each update and process the Upgrade Wizard in Installtool. Please notice that old extensions can break your update and need to be updated separetely.

Comment: Install instructions for 6.2.30 say it requires `PHP >5.3.7 up to 5.5`.  This suggests that 7 LTS is required.

Comment: Upvoted the answer but not accepted it.  The site is functional and throws no errors but is missing some major pieces (see edit #5).

Comment: Just seen your updates - seems like you you had alot of fun this day. About your column problem: In older TYPO3 versions there has often an extension named "templavoila" used to create page layouts (backend layouts) and content elements. Maybe in your case this extension was also used and has not been properly updated?


If not, the columns of a page are configured using backend layout records (be_layout table I guess). If they are still present you have to set the layout in in page settings. You can contact me on Skype teamgeist_medien_pab and I could take a look using Teamviewer.

Comment: Oh, it's been tons of fun.  Just love getting up at 3AM.  And I'm just a volunteer.  I'm going to try to contact via Skype, but can't promise results.  I'm on an older Windows 10 32-bit laptop with Skype preview and a VM running 6.2.  So no need to hold on to your hat.